# Logging to a file with Scalatra and Logback

Tags: scala, jetty, logback, scalatra

I'm trying to configure a standalone Scalatra app to log to a file.
I'm following the official manual and added this to `build.sbt`:

```
"ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % "runtime"
```

I also added `/src/main/resources/logback.xml` with the following config:

```
<configuration debug="false">
<appender name="file" class="ch.qos.logback.core.fileappender">
    <file>/var/log/webapp.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{hh:mm:ss.sss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.server" level="warn"/>
<logger name="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log" level="warn"/>

<root level="info">
    <appender-ref ref="file" />
</root>
</configuration>
```

But when I assemble a jar and run it, all stdout is full of DEBUG level logs from jetty, and no /var/log/webapp.log file is present.

I also had this error message while building:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you try removing ` % "runtime" ` from `ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3" % "runtime"` line

Comment: I tried and this did not help

Comment: I also tried to move logbook to `webapp/WEB-INF/logback.xml`, and running `sbt run jetty:start`. Still not log file and stdout is spammed with jetty logs.

Answer (score 0):

This is mainly because the logback-classic library is not available on classpath. Check if the resolvers are not overridden to ignore *MavenCentral*.